# where is JWT stored

Tags: node.js, jwt

Where does a JSON web token live? After doing jwt.sign and adding the payload / expiring date, what happens next, where is it stored ? I cant seem to find anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this : https://jwt.io/introduction/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JWT is not stored anywhere, its very existence contains everything. Its consisted of three parts, first one is hashing method, second one contains all the information you put there and the last one is signature so you can check if the token is valid or not (if you have secret).

This is actually the main reason JWT is so popular and used - as it can carry information through the multiple systems that can be verified by authorized systems.